# Local maxima at positive-semidefinite Hessian

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, derivatives, optimization

For a function $f$ having Hessian $H_f$, I have read at a few places that if $H_f$ is positive-semidefinite at a point, then $f$ will either have a local minima or a saddle point. But $f$ **cannot** have a local maxima at that point.

I just can't understand why is that so conceptually. Why can't $f$ have a local maxima under any circumstances at that point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically if $f$ is constant, then the Hessian is the zero matrix (which is PSD), so every point is a local maximum and a local minimum, although these are not strict maxima/minima. It is also possible to have a *strict* local maximum when the Hessian is zero: consider $f(x) = -x^4$ at $x=0$. (Thanks Robert Israel.)

Excluding this edge case of a zero Hessian however, you cannot have a local maximum. Suppose the Hessian $H_f$ at $x_0$ has a strictly positive eigenvalue. Let $v$ be the associated eigenvector. Then the univariate function $g(t) = f(x_0 + tv)$ has second derivative equal to $g''(t) = v^\top H_f v > 0$. Since the curvature of $g$ at zero is positive, there exist points $t$ arbitrarily close to $0$ such that $g(t)>g(0)$. This means $f(x_0 + tv) > f(x_0)$ for such $t$ as well.

Comment: The Hessian can be $0$ even if $f$ is not constant, and even if $f$ has a strict global maximum (e.g. $f(x) = -x^4$ at $x=0$).

Comment: @RobertIsrael When I said "excluding this edge case" I meant "when the Hessian is zero," but I see that this is not clear from how I wrote things. I'll edit my answer; thanks for the correction.

Comment: @angryavian Okay. I understand now, thank you!